# Failing to run memcached in win 7 xampp

Tags: php, windows, memcached, xampp

I am running win 7 , 64 bit and xampp 1.7.3. But can not install memcached.

Because,can not find the dll http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_memcache-cvs-20090703-5.3-VC6-x86.zip file in its location. I am sure, I can not install memcached in my system as this file is unavailable.

Can you please share this file?

Or do anyone know where is the exact location of the file?

I have tried with all the memcache dll from here: http://downloads.php.net/pierre/, but not working, showing errors.

If it is not possible to get the file, can any one say what is the other way to install memcached?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very hard to find but I found it :).. Installed and working perfectly on my system.

here is the link:

http://zhiliansns.googlecode.com/svn-history/r4/trunk/software/php_memcache-cvs-20090703-5.3-VC6-x86.zip

yeah I found it in a SVN repository :)

Answer (score 1):

For those whoe are still looking for the vc6 compiled memcache dll for php 5.3.x (always 32 bit in vc6) the file can be found at: http://code.google.com/p/thinkam/downloads/detail?name=php_memcache-cvs-20090703-5.3-VC6-x86.zip&can=2&q=

Took me about 5 hours to find the correct dll and hope some ppl find this u

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was hard but the new versions are available at http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

Feel free to ping me if you have any issue with these binaries or memcache in particular.

Comment: The main problem is that there is no way to find previous versions on this site... Unless you update your PHP version to whatever compatible build, you get the error message : "Apache is “Unable to initialize module” because of module's and PHP's API don't match" and you're left with upgrading your PHP version... Which is not possible on most production environments.

Comment: on the top,there is a comment from Yıldıray Meriç. he has given the dll life here to download. hope this will work you.

Comment: ah, right. I should put them somewhere else where the archive directory can be seen as a list.